# How to set different currency symbol according to website currency in multi-website on admin product edit page in magento 2.3.2

Tags: magento2.3

I have 2 website A And B with Currency CA and CB and I did all configuration For currency setup and currency rate, But on admin product edit page, it's still showing 'CA' Currency for both website product.

Comment: you run the setup,cache and permission command ??

Comment: Yes , already I did It